# Does Activemq ensure persistence?

Tags: queue, activemq-classic

I am using activemq queues in my project. Does it guarantee that messages will remain in the queue until dispatched even in the event of failures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if enabled to do so, yes...it will persist messages in a message store (file, database, etc) and only remove them after they have been successfully dequeued

see this page for details on persistence options: http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html

see this page for exception handling options: http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the broker persistence configuration, you need to insure the message producer delivery mode is persistent - see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/jms/MessageProducer.html).

On the consumer side the acknowledgement mode of the [session](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/jms/Session.html) will indicate when the message is acknowledged. Usually the default behavior of the JMS client is AUTO - the message is acknowledged when the receive method returns. But watch out, some wrapper like Spring might send the ACK before! In this case you may want to use Client acknowledgement or transactions...